# quasi-component in nested rectangles counterexample

Tags: general-topology

Example 115 of Steen & Seebach's "Counterexamples in Topology" is of a pair of vertical lines in the Euclidean plane at x = -1 & x = 1, called $L_1$ & $L_2$ along with an infinite collection of nested rectangles, $R_n$, which lay between the 2 vertical lines, and whose vertical sides get arbitrary close to $L_1$ & $L_2$ (each $R_n$ has height $2n$ and width $\frac{2n}{(n+1)}$ for $n=0,1,...$). The set of points in these lines and rectangles, $X$, inherit the topology of the Euclidean plane.

They state that $L_1\cup L_2 = X-\cup_n R_n$ is a quasi-component of X, i.e. the intersection of all sets containing a point in $L_1\cup L_2$ which are both open & closed (according to the definition on page 29). However, this doesn't make sense to me, since surely $L_1$ is both open and closed (it's a union of open sets, hence open, and it's the complement of $L_2\cup \cup_n R_n$ which is a union of open sets, hence $L_1$ is also closed).

Can anyone help me understand this example?

Answer (score 1):

$L_1$ and $L_2$ are *not* open in $X$. Due to the way the sides of the rectangles $R_n$ become increasingly close to $L_1$ and $L_2$ (and increasingly tall), any neighbourhood of any point in $L_1$ must intersect infinitely many of the rectangles $R_n$.

Fix $(-1, y_0) \in L_1$. Suppose $C \subseteq X$ contains $(-1, y_0)$ and is clopen. Since $C$ is open, there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that, for any $(x, y) \in X$,
$$d((x, y), (-1, y_0)) \le \varepsilon \implies (x, y) \in C.$$
Let $A_n$ be the left line segment of $R_n$, i.e.
$$A_n = \operatorname{conv}\left\{\left(-\frac{n}{n + 1}, -n\right), \left(-\frac{n}{n + 1}, n\right)\right\}.$$
Let $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that
$$N \ge \max\left\{\frac{1}{\varepsilon} - 1, |y_0|\right\}.$$
Suppose $n \ge N$. Then $|y_0| \le n$, hence
$$\left(-\frac{n}{n+1},y_0\right) \in A_n.$$
Additionally,
$$d\left(\left(-\frac{n}{n+1},y_0\right), (-1, y_0)\right) = \left|-\frac{n}{n+1} + 1\right| = \frac{1}{n+1} \le \varepsilon \implies \left(-\frac{n}{n+1},y_0\right) \in C.$$
Note that $C \cap R_n$ is clopen. Since $R_n$ is connected, and $C \cap R_n$ is non-trivial by the above argument, $R_n \subseteq C$ for all $n \ge N$.

On the right side, we similarly see
$$n \ge N \implies \left(\frac{n}{n+1},y_0\right) \in R_n \subseteq C,$$
and this sequence converges to $(1, y_0)$. As $C$ is closed, $(1, y_0) \in C$ too. That is, a point in $L_1$ implies a point in $L_2$ too. As $L_1$ and $L_2$ are connected subsets of $X$, we get $L_1 \cup L_2 \subseteq C$.

Conversely, $L_1 \cup L_2 \cup \bigcup_{n \ge N} R_n$ is a family of clopen subsets of $X$ (as $N$ ranges over $\Bbb{N}$) whose intersection is $L_1 \cup L_2$, and which contain $(-1, y_0)$. Hence $L_1 \cup L_2$ is indeed the quasicomponent of $(-1, y_0)$.